# Define dependencies when using tikz externalize

Tags: tikz-pgf

At the beginning of my document I have `\input{tikzcommands}` where `tikzcommands.tex` contains global settings that I want to use in the TikZ pictures. For example, in this file I define some styles.

The problem, when using the `externalize` library it doesn't recognizes when something changed with the `tikzcommands.tex`. I tried to add something like `\tikzpicturedependsonfile{tikzcommands.tex}` at the beginning of the TikZ environment, but it didn't help.

What is the right way to make `figureA.tex` (which is included using `input`) depended on a settings file `tikzcommands.tex`?

***EDIT:***
 Due to the comment of @Psirus I *know* that I'm doing something wrong. But I still don't manage to have the desired behavior, even when trying to use `mode=list and make`. Here is my original pseudo MWE.

First, I load `TikZ`

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes,calc,decorations.pathreplacing,patterns}
```

Then, I have the following

```
\makeatletter
\IfFileExists{tikzexternal.sty}
{%
  \usetikzlibrary{external}%
  \tikzexternalize%
  \tikzsetexternalprefix{figures/cache/}%
  \renewcommand{\todo}[2][]{%
    \tikzexternaldisable\@todo[##1]{##2}\tikzexternalenable}%
}%
{%
  % Empty else case
}%
\makeatother
```

Which checks is `externalize` is available, or not. This part I have to make the code compatible with older distributions of `pgf` which do not support the `externalize` package.

Then I have an included file `tikzcommands.tex` which contains (among other things)

```
\tikzset{
        robot/.style={thick,fill=green!#1},
        obstacle/.style={fill=red!80,thick}
}
```

Finally in the document's body I have `input`s of the following form:

```
\input{./figures/figureA}
```

In `figureA` I use the styles `robot` and `obstacle`.

I want to use externalize in such a way that even when I just change the file `tikzcommands.tex` the figures which depend on it will be re-compiled.

I understand that I have to:

1. Change the loading of the `externalize` package.
2. Add something  before each `input` which depends on the `tikzcommands.tex`
3. Probably change the building workflow. Currently I'm using `latexmk` alone.

I tried several combinations but nothing worked for me. I hope someone could draw the way to accomplish this.

Comment: please share your code (MWE), it makes it easier to debug for others. Furthermore, there are several ways to use the external library, please show/state the exact process.

Comment: `\tikzpicturedependsonfile` is only supported for `mode=list and make`, which is not the default. What mode are you using?

Answer (score 3):

First off, I don't know `latexmk`, so my solution doesn't integrate nicely, but I guess you can adapt my crude `Makefile` to your `latexmk` logic.

The main file, here `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\IfFileExists{tikzexternal.sty}
{%
  \usetikzlibrary{external}%
  \tikzset{external/mode=list and make}
  \tikzexternalize%
  \tikzsetexternalprefix{figures/cache/}%
}%
{%
  % Empty else case
}%
\makeatother

\input{tikzcommands}

\begin{document}
    \input{./figures/figureA}
\end{document}
```

Instead of generating the pictures directly, `pdflatex` now writes a `main.makefile` for the images. The dependency on `tikzcommands.tex` is set in the picture file `figure/figureA.tex`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzpicturedependsonfile{tikzcommands.tex}
    \draw[myRectangle] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And to make the example complete, a dummy `tikzcommands.tex`:

```
\tikzset{
        myRectangle/.style={thick}
}
```

Now you can run `make -f main.makefile` to make the pictures, and only rebuild them when their sources or `tikzcommands.tex` changes. A very crude `Makefile` would be:

```
main.pdf: main.tex
    pdflatex main.tex;
    make -f main.makefile
    latexmk -pdf main.tex
```

But this runs `pdflatex` once unnecessarily, and really displays my ignorance regarding `latexmk`. I'm sure you can add the line `make -f main.makefile` to the `latexmk` logic so that it is run after a first pass of `pdflatex`.

Comment: Thanks for the effort! After changing the `tikzcommands.tex` and running `pdflatex`, when I invoke the `make -f main.makefile` I get `All images exist now. Use make -B to re-generate them.` It doesn't see the change in the file. Can it be a path problem in `\tikzpicturedependsonfile{tikzcommands.tex}`? `figureA` is in `./figures` and `'tikzcommands.tex` is in `.`

Comment: Once the `main.makefile` is created, the images are (re)build when I run `make -f main.makefile`. When I then change something in `tikzcommands.tex`, `make -f main.makefile` (re)builds the pictures AND outputs `All images exist now...`. There is no need to run `pdflatex` if you only change `tikzcommands.tex` to rebuild the pictures. My directory is set up just as yours.

Comment: Something is still not working for me. I I change something in `tikzcommands.tex` then neither `make -f...` nor `make -B...` nor `pdflatex` builds the right final result. I don't understand.

Comment: Even when `tikzcommands` was changed, `make -B...` returns `Nothing to be done for `main.makefile'.` Somehow, it doesn't detect that there was a change with the `tikzcommand`